# RequiredFieldValidatorfor textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question. I have a textarea and 2 textboxes. What I want to do is to check if textarea is filled, other 2 textboxes must not be empty. We can give messagebox like this (please necessary fields must be filled)

This is my code :

```
<textarea id="txtCustomerRepresentatorOpinion" name="txtCustomerRepresentatorOpinion" runat="server" style="width: 99%"></textarea>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerRepresentatorOpinion"
       ValidationGroup="Save"  Text="*" ClientValidationFunction="txtArea" />

<telerik:RadTextBox Width="321px" runat="server" ID="txtCustomerRepresentatorOpinionNameSurname" TextMode="SingleLine" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="VldAdi" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerRepresentatorOpinionNameSurname"
       ValidationGroup="Save"  Text="*"  ErrorMessage="Lütfen Adı Soyadı giriniz."/>

<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpCustomerRepresentatorOpinionDate"  ZIndex="9999" Style="vertical-align: middle;" runat="server">
</telerik:RadDatePicker>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="VldTarih" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="rdpCustomerRepresentatorOpinionDate"
      ValidationGroup="Save"  Text="*"  ErrorMessage="Lütfen Tarihi giriniz.">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Which side should I use (client side or server side)? How i do this job? Right now, I can show messages but textarea is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `textarea` into an asp.net TextBox Control with `TextMode="MultiLine"`. Then a `RequiredFieldValidator` will work.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCustomerRepresentatorOpinion" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required field" ControlToValidate="txtCustomerRepresentatorOpinion"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Yes it does. Check the console for javascript errors and the `ValidationGroup`

Comment: There are many text area.İf i can do this one, i will do all of them.When the user don't enters input the textarea,then i  click save and it works properly.But when user enter some inputs textarea,i want to show a messagebox (these textboxs must be filled before saving).

Comment: İ use requiredFieldValidator for textboxs.Also should i use requiredFieldValidator for the textarea.

Comment: It does not matter if you use TextBox or TextBox multiline to use a Validator